# Dynamically pass array name

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I have 3 arrays...

```
var arr1 = new Array("qqq","www","eee","rrr");
var arr2 = new Array("aaa","sss","ddd","fff");
var arr3 = new Array("zzz","xxx","ccc","vvv");
```

and I have some radio buttons with values matching to these, is it possible to use the value in the radio buttons to work on the array, e.g.

```
checkedRadioButton.length
```

to get the length of the array which is named the same as the value from the radio selection?

Hope this is clear enough

Sorry for confusion. Here is some more example;

```
                <label>Radio buttons</label>
                <input type="radio" name="radioGroup" id="s01" value="s01" checked="checked">
                <label for="s01">Choice 1</label>

                <input type="radio" name="radioGroup" id="s02" value="s02">
                <label for="s02">Choice 2</label>

                <input type="radio" name="radioGroup" id="s03" value="s03">
                <label for="s03">Choice 3</label>
```

if user selects option 3, and I wanted to show the values from the 3rd array, what would be the best way to go about it?

Comment: Can you post your relevant HTML output of those radio buttons please as well as the actual relevant arrays? This is a little confusing, you say the values in the arrays match names of radio buttons but then say you want to be able to get the length of an array with the same name of the radio selection. Does that mean the values match the radio button names or the array names match the radio button names? Seeing the actual HTML markup and you actual arrays will help a lot to make this clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a JavaScript object literal and use the array name as the key:

```
var data = {
    arr1 : ["qqq","www","eee","rrr"],
    arr2 : ["aaa","sss","ddd","fff"],
    arr3 : ["zzz","xxx","ccc","vvv"]
}

var buttonVal = "arr1"; // depends on your HTML code

alert(data[buttonVal].length);
```

Answer (score 1):

As can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/82XY5/

Html:

```
<form action="">
<input id='arr1' type="radio" name="arr" value="arr1">arr1<br>
<input id='arr2' type="radio" name="arr" value="arr2">arr2<br>
<input id='arr3' type="radio" name="arr" value="arr3">arr3
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
var arrayContainer = {};
arrayContainer["arr1"] = new Array("qqq","www","eee","rrr");
arrayContainer["arr2"] = new Array("aaa","sss","ddd","fff");
arrayContainer["arr3"] = new Array("zzz","xxx","ccc","vvv");

var value = document.getElementById("arr1").value;

alert(arrayContainer[value].length);
```

What it does is:

- add all the arrays to a common scope (in the example, the common scope is `arrayContainer`). If they are global variables then the common scope is `window`.
- use the `[]` operator to access the property (variable) with the desired name.

**Note:** It is not necessary to use the `new` keyword for arrays and objects.
 You can just do `var arr1 = ["qqq","www","eee","rrr"];`